# How to have stacked sns.barplot without a duplication in the legend?

Tags: python, seaborn

```
g=sns.barplot(x='depth', y='nodes', hue='end id', data=df, palette=sns.color_palette("gnuplot2", 5))
g1=sns.barplot(x='depth', y='initial', hue='end id', data=df, palette=sns.color_palette("gnuplot2", 5))
```

How can I force the legend to show only only once the label per hue and not twice?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been nice if you had provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to test the solution against your particular use-case.

In any case, my solution is a bit of a hack, but if you are sure that the legend entries are exact duplicates

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips)
ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips)

h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h[:int(len(h)/2)], l[:int(len(l)/2)])
```

[image]

Comment: That’s what I wanted. To slice the legend’s labels.